# Understanding jiffy update in work queues

Tags: c, timer, linux-kernel, sleep, kernel-module

I'm trying to understand workqueue better using the following kernel module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/workqueue.h>
#include <linux/jiffies.h>

static DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(my_wq);
static int condition = 0;

/* declare a work queue*/
static struct work_struct wrk;

static void work_handler(struct work_struct *work)
{ 
    pr_info("Waitqueue module handler %s, ms cnt is %u\n", __FUNCTION__, jiffies_to_msecs(jiffies));
    msleep(3000);
    pr_info("Wake up the sleeping module\n");
    condition = 1;
    wake_up_interruptible(&my_wq);
}

static int __init my_init(void)
{
    pr_info("Wait queue example, ms count is %u\n", jiffies_to_msecs(jiffies));

    INIT_WORK(&wrk, work_handler);
    schedule_work(&wrk);

    pr_info("Going to sleep %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    wait_event_interruptible(my_wq, condition != 0);

    pr_info("woken up by the work job at %ums\n", jiffies_to_msecs(jiffies));
    return 0;
}

void my_exit(void)
{
    pr_info("waitqueue example cleanup\n");
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);
MODULE_AUTHOR("Aijaz Baig <aijazbaig1@gmail.com>");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Output:

```
Jan  3 06:53:27 buildroot user.info kernel: Wait queue example, ms count is 6144890
Jan  3 06:53:27 buildroot user.info kernel: Going to sleep my_init
Jan  3 06:53:27 buildroot user.info kernel: Waitqueue module handler work_handler, ms cnt is 6144890
Jan  3 06:53:30 buildroot user.info kernel: Wake up the sleeping module
Jan  3 06:53:30 buildroot user.info kernel: woken up by the work job at 6147900ms
```

Two noticeable things here:

1. The ms difference, after the sleep is actually 3010ms
2. the jiffy count under the *__init* function and the *work_handler* function is EXACTLY the same

Running it (removing and re-inserting the module) for a second time gives:

```
Jan  3 06:59:28 buildroot user.info kernel: Wait queue example, ms count is 6506580
Jan  3 06:59:28 buildroot user.info kernel: Going to sleep my_init
Jan  3 06:59:29 buildroot user.info kernel: Waitqueue module handler work_handler, ms cnt is 6506640
Jan  3 06:59:31 buildroot user.info kernel: Wake up the sleeping module
Jan  3 06:59:31 buildroot user.info kernel: woken up by the work job at 6509660ms
```

This time around, the jiffy counts in the `__init` and the `work_handler()` functions are different. However the sleep duration is 3020ms.

Which brings me to these questions:

1. Is it normal to have the actual sleep duration this different from the one intended (a difference of ~15ms -20ms)?
2. How come for the first run, there was NO update in the jiffy count whatsoever?

Comment: 1. Read what msleep() guarantees, I guess it will be something like "sleep for **at least** given time".

Comment: 2. Task has been immediately scheduled on the same CPU **without any intermediate work**.

Comment: What exactly is *immediate* in the kernel context so as to prevent the jiffy count from being updated? A function call at the very least requires setting up a frame if nothing else. That should update the jiffy count or is my understanding of jiffy not up to the mark?

Comment: Why it should update jiffy? Jiffy AFAIU is being updated when scheduling happens (meaning via IRQ context).

Comment: can you please link to a post explaining how are they updated? I believe earlier it used to be incremented on every timer tick, the timer being configured based on the value of HZ. RIght? This seems to have changed now

Comment: And how it was updated thru timer? I'm pretty sure nothing has been changed in the algorithm of updating the jiffy after timer is fired.